# helm-projectile find file doesn't ignore some files

Tags: spacemacs, projectile, helm-projectile

I'm using `helm-projectile` in `spacemacs`. I want `helm-projectile` to ignore all the files in `.stack-work` directory when running `helm-projectile-find-file`.

I added `.stack-work` in `projectile-globally-ignored-directories` variable:

[image: the result of C-h v projectile-globally-ignored-directories]

But the result of `helm-projectile-find-file` still contains following:

[image: result of SPC p f intero]

All files in `.stack-work` were successfully ignored, except those 4 files. I cannot figure out why that 4 files are still showing up, while others don't.

I also tried to create`.projectile` in the root directory of the project with the following contents:

```
-/.stack-work
```

The result was, `helm-projectile-grep` seems to ignore `.stack-work` with `.projectile`. But there was no difference in `helm-projectile-find-file`; it still shows up that 4 files.

Why are that 4 files are showing up in the result? What should I do in order to completely ignore files in `.stack-work`?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use `.projectile` list of ignored files, you should try with

```
(setq projectile-enable-caching t)
(setq projectile-indexing-method 'native)
```

... inside your config file. It looks like ignoring by `.projectile` list is currently working with native indexing method.
More details: [in github](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/issues/92) .
With `alien` method .gitignore is working well (but `alien` is not respecting `.projectile` list).