# Ignore .folder inside projectile project

Tags: spacemacs, projectile

In spacemacs, I want `SPC p f` to ignore one directory in the files it suggests. I followed the [Projectile docs for ignoring files](http://projectile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/#ignoring-files). I added a line to both my `~/.emacs.d/.projectile` file and the `.projectile` file in the root of the project. None of the following seem to work for ignoring a folder:

`-.folder
-.folder/**
-**/.folder
-.folder/**/*`

(note that the folder to ignore does have a `.` in its name)

Am I missing some reindex command? I tried `SPC p I` which did *something*, but didn't fix this problem. Closing and opening Emacs did nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/44245/16781), which I report entirely here

> if you want to use .projectile list of ignored files, you should try
>   with
>
> (setq projectile-enable-caching t) (setq projectile-indexing-method
>   'native)
>
> ... inside your config file. It looks like ignoring by .projectile
>   list is currently working with native indexing method. More details:
>   in github . With alien method .gitignore is working well (but alien is
>   not respecting .projectile list).